# How would I get my game over scene to not fill up my entire screen in Swift Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

My game ends when my hero node collides with the enemy node. Then my Game Over menu is supposed to pop up but it takes over the entire screen. I want it to be able to show the GameScene in background and the Game Over menu to be smaller so it doesn't take over the whole view.How would I accomplish this. This is the code I have. Thank you.

```
        func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact){

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory &&  
        secondBody.categoryBitMask ==       
        EnemyCategory {
        mikeParachute.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)

        let scene = GameOverScene(size: self.frame.size)
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)

     }
          }
```

Comment: Change the size of the frame. You initialise the scene with self.frame.size. That sets it to the size of the current parent views size.

Comment: How would I do that? Im new to swift.

Comment: Replace the bit: self.frame.size to whatever CGSize you want.

Comment: I added this  let scene = GameOverScene(size: CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)) and I see a dark screen only.

Comment: That's half a pixel wide and have a pixel high so i'm not surprised you can't see it.

Comment: I did it to 20 and 20 also and the same thing happened.

Comment: OK. well there's probably an error elsewhere.